# Not able to run tests after using @Factory annotation in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

**Here is the structure of my class:**

```
package com.gex.base.helper;

public class InitializeDriver extends BrowserFactory 
{

    HashMap<String, String> authenticationMap;

    @Factory(dataProvider="authentication", dataProviderClass=DataProviderList.class)
    public InitializeDriver(String userName, String uPassword)
    {
        authenticationMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        authenticationMap.put("UserName", userName);
        authenticationMap.put("Password", uPassword);
    }


    @BeforeTest
     public void Gexlogin() 
      {
          LoginPF objLogin=PageFactory.initElements(BrowserFactory.driver, LoginPF.class);
           System.out.println("Logging into GEx");
           objLogin.loginToDGEx(authenticationMap.get("UserName"), authenticationMap.get("Password"));
          System.out.println("Successfully Logged into GEx");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void directLogout(){

        // logout from application
        LogoutPF objLogoutTest = PageFactory.initElements(BrowserFactory.driver, LogoutPF.class);
        objLogoutTest.LogOffGEx();
        extent.flush();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

**LoginToGEx is a function in another class like as:**

```
public void loginToGEx(String strUsername, String strPassword)
{
    username.sendKeys(strUsername)
    password.sendKeys(strPassword);
    loginButton.click();
    System.out.println("Successfully Logged into GEx");
}
```

**DataProviderClass**

```
public class DataProviderList {

    @DataProvider(name="authentication")
    public static Object[][] authentication()
    {
        return new Object[][] {
            {"abc", "123"}, 
            {"xyz", "456"},
            };
    }

}
```

**In another class there is @Test extending InitializeDriver class.**

```
    public class SampleTest extends InitializeDriver {

        public SampleTest(String userName, String uPassword) {
            super(userName, uPassword);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Test
        public void CreateNewEngTest() throws InterruptedException
        {
            test=extent.createTest("Eng Test","Create Eng Test");
            -Code (which is working fine before using @Factory)-----------------------
```

Testng.xml structure:

```
<suite name="Sample Project" verbose="1" >

   <test name="Sample Test" group-by-instances="true" preserve-order="true">
  <classes>
            <class name="com.gex.base.testscripts.SampleTest" />                     
  </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

My Question is:
Before using @Factory with dataprovider--my tests were running fine but when I used @Factory annotation then nothing happens..
In SampleTest Class this constructor gets created itself..may be this causing issue.

```
public SampleTest(String userName, String uPassword) {
            super(userName, uPassword);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
```

Please guide how to make tests run using @Factory

**Also 1 more thing** if I define factory annotation with my @test scenario then everytime I need to login..and I have many testcases and wanted to run login once execute all @test scenatios then logout and start again with another set of username&password...not everytime when @test starts.  Is this scenario possible?  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you annotated the constructor with `@Factory` annotation and then used inheritance.

To keep the inheritance, etc you should annotate the `SampleTest` class with `@Factory`

Like this:

```
public class SampleTest extends InitializeWebDriver {
    private String userName, password;

    @Factory(dataProvider="authentication", dataProviderClass=DataProviderList.class)
    public SampleTest(String userName, String password) {
        super(userName, password)
    }
}


public class InitializeDriver extends BrowserFactory {
    private String userName, password;

    public InitializeDriver(String userName, String uPassword)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

This will cause `@Factory` to pass the arguments from DataProvider to your `InitializeDriver` class and save it as instance variables.

Then you can use those variables like in your `@BeforeTest` method:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void Gexlogin() {
     LoginPF objLogin=PageFactory.initElements(BrowserFactory.driver, LoginPF.class);
     System.out.println("Logging into GEx");
     objLogin.loginToDGEx(userName, password); //changed to instance variables
     System.out.println("Successfully Logged into GEx");
}
```

EDIT:
The `@BeforeTest` method will only execute once because TestNG treats `@Factory` tests as a single test case!
If you want to log in before each test, you need to use `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rafał Laskowski. Now it is logging in using one set of username and password.{"xyz", "456"}  not for {"abc", "123"}.  What it does now--is first it is logging in then run Sample test 2 times. But I want to run using one set of username and password..run Sample test scenario then logout again log in using another set of username password and run Sample test scenario.

Comment: @Samy Change `@BeforeTest` to `@BeforeMethod` :) I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks Rafal..yes now it is working fine after changing BeforeTest and AfterTest to BeforeMethod and AfterMethod